# Rotate a byte array format image with odd resolutions other than 90,180,270,360

Tags: java, android, image-processing, arrays

I want a byte operation logic to rotate an image (byte array format) with 5 degrees(-5d to 5d).

Am getting these bytes from onCameraPreview method. So i want this logic using byte operations to make the logic work fast. as it works for every frame of drawing.

Comment: Image rotation is costly operation. its not a good idea to use repeatedly on every frame of drawing.

Comment: Hi UVR,
If require i can guide you to rotate by converting it to bitmap and using matrix, which is working fine for me.

Comment: "Resolutions" isn't the right word. "Odd angles" or "non-perpendicular angles" might be more correct. I've voted to close, as there is not one good answer here, and most/all published algorithms require floating point math and sine/cosine lookup or calculation at minimum.